Open Graph images - priority order and size preference?
LinkedIn is now using a thumbnail version of the Open Graph image when the URL is external and shared onto LinkedIn. The thumbnail version seems to be 120px by 72px.
When our meticulously worked upon OG image of 1200px by 630px is shown in a much smaller context (the new thumbnail size), it doesn't make any sense.
For this, we prepared a smaller version that would make sense in a 120px by 72px view. Then we updated our Open Graph tags with the proportions specified across two images:
<meta property="og:image" content="https://urlToBiggerImage" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />

<meta property="og:image" content="https://urlToThumbnailImage" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="120" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="72" />

However, LinkedIn is still using the bigger image even in a thumbnail context.
As per https://ogp.me:

If a tag can have multiple values, just put multiple versions of the same  tag on your page. The first tag (from top to bottom) is given preference during conflicts.

Given this, I am wary of putting the thumbnail version on top and having it be the go-to in all contexts, especially in non LinkedIn contexts.
LinkedIn in my opinion should be reading the additional meta-data on these og:images and picking a correct image for each context (thumbnail, full preview image) on their website (pick the bigger image when showing a big OG image, and pick the smaller image when showing a thumbnail OG image).
What can I do to make this happen?
